# Concatenate strings and variables giving typeerror, unsupported operand for 'Tag'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have followed Data Science Dojo's tutorial on Web Scraping here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI
I think my BeautifulSoup python is all good and operational.
But my final concatenate string and variable function is giving an error.

This is strange because the format is exactly the same as in the tutorial.
Any ideas how I can concatenate my strings and variables to run the code without errors, therefore creating the final csv?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

my_url = ('https://www.frogbikes.com/lightweight-kids-bikes/')
uClient = uReq(my_url)
bike_cats = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
frog_soup = soup(bike_cats, "html.parser")

bike_styles = frog_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item bike"})


filename = "products.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "category, size(cm), age, start_price\n"

f.write(headers)

for bike_style in bike_styles:
    category = bike_style.a.h2
    info = bike_style.find("div", {"class": "info group"})
    size_list = info.div.findAll("span")
    size = size_list[1]
    info2 = info.findAll("div")
    age = info2[1].span
    start_price = info2[2].span

    # print("category: " + category)
    # print("size: " + size)
    # print("age: " + age)
    # print("start_price: " + start_price)

    f.write(category + "," + size + "," + age + "," + start_price + "\n")

f.close()
```

Error message:

> f.write(category + "," + size + "," + age + "," + start_price + "\n")
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tag' and 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `.text` to all the variables you are trying to save:

```
category = bike_style.a.h2.text
info = bike_style.find("div", {"class": "info group"})
size_list = info.div.findAll("span")
size = size_list[1].text
info2 = info.findAll("div")
age = info2[1].span.text
start_price = info2[2].span.text
```

The reason you are getting the error is because your variables are `html` tags i.e. £234. To get the actual `string` from the `html` element, call `.text`, which returns the `str` i.e. `£234`